# why should I pass the `filename` to the `SetAccessControl` method?

Tags: c#, security, file-access

I'm going to set the full access permission to a file (`fileName`). I found a code sample:

```
var security = IO.File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

security.AddAccessRule(new Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
    Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

IO.File.SetAccessControl(fileName, security);
```

It is working well but I don't understand why should I pass the `filename` to the `SetAccessControl` method (I already provided it in the first line)? I made a change to the code and see this is working too:

```
var security = IO.File.GetAccessControl(anotherFileName);

security.AddAccessRule(new Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
    Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

IO.File.SetAccessControl(fileName, security);
```

So what is the use of `anotherFileName` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetAccessControl` will get the [`FileSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx).

From MSDN:

> Represents the access control and audit security for a file. [...] This class represents access and audit rights as a set of rules.

A `FileSecurity` is not dependent on a particular file, so you can use one `FileSecurity` on multiple files to set identical access and audit rights.

This is why you need to specify the filename.

An alternative would be to use the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
var security = fileInfo.GetAccessControl();
// [...]
fileInfo.SetAccessControl(security);
```

The [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.filesecurity.aspx) from MSDN:

```
FileSecurity()
```

Will create an empty `FileSecurity` object.

```
FileSecurity(String, AccessControlSections)
```

Creates an empty `FileSecurity` object from the specified file using the specified values of the `AccessControlSections` enumeration.

Comment: `A FileSecurity is not dependent on a particular file`. So why it is getting a filename in its constructor?

Comment: What if I want to get some default security without providing a file name?

Comment: +1. @HosseinNarimaniRad - you pass file name to construct ACL that matches one of that particular file. If you don't want to specify file name - use [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3bdz93k.aspx) and set everything by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Security information (ACL) is not tied to object, so you can get current value for one file and apply to any other file.

This is exactly the same as `string name = person.Name` - `name` is not tied to a `person`, just some property of one.